# How to add custom HTML elements and images to a blog in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog in Django. Most of the tutorials and examples available shows just retrieving some content from the database and displaying it dynamically on the predefined HTML structure.

After looking at some solution I found something called flatpages in Django which provide the facility to write HTML. But its recommended to use it for About Us and Contact Us kind of pages. Should I use this?

I want to do it as I can write my own HTML data for each blog and add some images so that the structure of HTML should not be similar in each blog.

For example, In the case of WordPress, it allows the user to completely write each part of the blog except the heading part and the structure of HTML is not constant always.

I want such functionality. Please help.

Comment: Did you find out the answer? I am looking for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is to upload images and embed them as html in your content field. This can be done using a WYSIWYG Editor such as CKEditor. In CK you can write your text, format it and upload files. You could use django-ckeditor to do the heavy lifting for you: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

In your template you then have to render your content with safe filter so that the content will be rendered as html:

```
    {{ post.content |safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the static directory? It stores the static content like CSS, Image etc. Create the Static and join it with the `BASE_DIR` in settings.py file. A full explanation is given here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yes, I have gone through. it's just about managing static files like CSS and JavaScript. If you are familiar with Wordpress or check out some common blogs you will understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of packages that already do this. You can refer to [Django Packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/blogs/) and pick the one that suits your needs the best.

[Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) is one of the most common ones. I personally have not used it.
I've seen [Django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) being used at one of my previous jobs. It was quite powerful, but I *personally* did not like it a lot.

If you'd like to create your own CMS, you could go for a very basic structure like

```
class BlogImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    content = models.TextField()  # be sure to validate that this does not contain bad code
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag)
```

Give the users a WYSIWYG editor like [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/). If users want to include images the just need to use the URL to it. If they want to upload, give them a modal or some different page to upload the image and copy the link to the image into the HTML markup

Comment: Thanks, man. This is what I was looking for. But can you please tell me one more thing CKEditor would be great to give to users but if in case I want to write my own HTML content for each blog and do all kinds of stuff manually, may I do this?